# Parse.Promise in mocha before() block always triggers timeout

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, mocha.js, parse-server

I'm trying to set up a Parse.User in a Mocha before() hook for a set of Mocha tests.  If I return the Parse.User.signup() promise from the before() block, then Mocha always times out.  If I use a function(done) declaration and return .then(done,done) on the Parse.Promise I get a timeout.

How should I structure a Mocha before() so that calling a Parse.User function that returns a Promise will execute?

My current Parse Javascript code:

```
describe("a thing", function(){

    var user;

    before(function(){
        var test_user = new Parse.User();
        test_user.setUsername("test_user");
        test_user.setPassword("test_password");
        test_user.setEmail("test@testy.test");
        return test_user.signUp({"DisplayName": "test_display"},null);
    });

   it("tests a thing", function()......);
});
```

I've also tried:

```
describe("a thing", function(){

    var user;

    before(function(done){
        var test_user = new Parse.User();
        test_user.setUsername("test_user");
        test_user.setPassword("test_password");
        test_user.setEmail("test@testy.test");
        test_user.signUp({"DisplayName": "test_display"},null).then(done,done);
    });

   it("tests a thing", function()......);
});
```

Comment: First thing to try is to increase the timeout. Sometimes operations take longer than we expect.

Comment: Yeah, if both methods are timing out, it's most likely because the operation takes more than 2 seconds.

Comment: There was a bit of latency to the DB and therefore the timeout was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was indeed timeout caused either by talking to my local MongoDB container or on my CI server speaking to a remote DB.

In environments where I anticipate longer response times I run my mocha tests with an additional timeout flag:

```
npm run test -- -t 10000
```

Solution was indicated by robertklep